# Hi, I do not use ng-click event in my Controller with Style Guide Definitions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't use `ng-click` event in my Controller with **style guide definitions**.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('starter.controllers')
        .controller('MapsCtrl', maps);

    function maps($ionicLoading, $compile, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        var citiesList = [
            {
                id: 1,
                city: 'City One',
                desc: 'This is the best city in the world!',
                lat: -25.5511123,
                long: -49.4059869
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                city: 'City Two',
                desc: 'This city is aiiiiite!',
                lat: -25.481642,
                long: -49.293805
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                city: 'City Three',
                desc: 'This is the second best city in the world!',
                lat: -25.5867087,
                long: -49.1551404
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                city: 'City Four',
                desc: 'This city is live!',
                lat: -25.424667,
                long: -49.1605463
            }
        ];

        var _siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.5511123, -49.4059869); // city One default
        var _hospitalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.481642, -49.293805); // city Two default

        var _mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: _siteLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        var _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), _mapOptions);
        var _markers = [];

        var createMarker = function(info) {
            var _marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: _map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                title: info.city
            });
            _marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

            var _htmlInfo = '<div><a ng-click="vm.clickTest(' + info.id + ')"><h2>' + _marker.title + '</h2></a>' + _marker.content + "</div>";
            var _compiled = $compile(_htmlInfo)(vm);

            var _infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: _compiled[0]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(_marker, 'click', function() {
                // infoWindow.setContent(_htmlInfo);
                _infoWindow.open(_map, _marker);
            });

            _markers.push(_marker);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < citiesList.length; i++) {
            createMarker(citiesList[i]);
        };

        // BEGIN -- Destionation
        var _directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var _directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var _request = {
            origin: _siteLatLng,
            destination: _hospitalLatLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        _directionsService.route(_request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                _directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        _directionsDisplay.setMap(_map);
        // END -- Destination

        // Declare variables as vm
        vm.map = _map;
        vm.markers = _markers;


        vm.centerOnMe = function() {
            if (!vm.map)
                return;

            vm.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Getting current location...',
                showBackdrop: false
            });
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                vm.map.setCenter(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
                );
                $ionicLoading.hide();

                var _position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                var _marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: vm.map,
                    position: _position,
                    title: 'You are here!',
                    icon: 'images/places/place_black.png'
                });

                console.log( _position );
                console.log( pos);
                console.log( vm.map );

                var _htmlInfo = '<div><h1>You!</h1> Content text.</div>';
                var _compiled = $compile(_htmlInfo)(vm);
                var _infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: _compiled[0]
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(_marker, 'click', function() {
                    // infoWindow.setContent(_htmlInfo);
                    _infoWindow.open(_map, _marker);
                });
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
            });
        };

        vm.clickTest = function(_id) {
            console.log('Clicked!!!', _id);

            alert(citiesList[_id - 1].city + ' is clicked! :D');
        };
    };

})();
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.$apply is not a function
(anonymous function)    @   ionic.bundle.js:53438
eventHandler    @   ionic.bundle.js:11713


//ionic.bundle.js  line: 53438

/**
 * @private
 */
.factory('$ionicNgClick', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return function(scope, element, clickExpr) {
    var clickHandler = angular.isFunction(clickExpr) ?
      clickExpr :
      $parse(clickExpr);

    element.on('click', function(event) {
      scope.$apply(function() {  // (x) Uncaught TypeError: scope.$apply is not a function
        clickHandler(scope, {$event: (event)});
      });
    });

    // Hack for iOS Safari's benefit. It goes searching for onclick handlers and is liable to click
    // something else nearby.
    element.onclick = noop;
  };
}])
```

Please, help me, if possible!
Thanks!

---

[image: Screenshot]

If I click in title from Window, return the error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller used as ControllerAs you reference the scope with `this`.

try something like:

```
var _compiled = $compile(_htmlInfo)(this);
...
this.clickTest =...
```

See [here for more details](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax)

Comment: Thanks to answer @zmii, but a Style guide definition I do not use `$scope` but use `vm` in Controller.
You did not know?
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#function-declarations-to-hide-implementation-details

Comment: It was rhetorical question. You my use ControllerAs syntax. Still you've got error inside FACTORY, not controller. So please ming that factories doesn't have scopes defined. You may inject one there

Comment: Thanks @zmii, but I do not understand how make in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642138/how-to-include-inject-functions-which-use-scope-into-a-controller-in-angularjs

Comment: This $ionicNgClick factory is a native angular. I must overwrite his?

Comment: No. that is something interesting then... Please provide more code of controller.

Comment: In controllerAs in controller you make this is the beginning `var vm = this;` ? If not why do you play with `vm`?

Comment: Inside the controller used as ControllerAs you reference the scope with `this`. See here for more details http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: There is an issue here that you may be interested to read https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3058

Comment: This is a style guide definition, @zmii
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#function-declarations-to-hide-implementation-details

Comment: Thanks for answer @zmii

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help @zmii

I could not solve this problem so I decided to use $ scope for the Click event. Look:

```
function maps($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile, $stateParams) {

   ...

   var _compiled = $compile(_htmlInfo)($scope);
```

Reference;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384592/3332734